# `scale` in R with no normal distribution

Tags: r, distributions

The function called scale, in R, does the same of subtracting the mean and dividing by the sd each element.

So the scale function allows to take in count differente parameter with different scale.

# Manually scaling
   (x - mean(x)) / sd(x)

# Default scaling
   scale(x)

But, does it make sense scale a **variable if it doesn't have a normal distribution**?

Andrea

Comment: This is not a good question for stackoverflow since it is not a coding question.

Comment: It depends on your purpose. In general answer is no. But for representation - why not.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the issue, but keep in mind that, if you've got data, you can compute the mean and standard deviation. Then you can subtract the mean from each point and divide by the standard deviation. Now you've got a new data set with mean 0 and standard deviation 1, which is often helpful and the reason we do scaling in the first place.

As User7598 noted, scaling doesn't change many of the other useful things we want to know about that data, so it's a nice way to make your data more digestible without altering it in a bigger way (like doing a log transform).

Comment: @German "In general" the answer is yes!  When the units in which we measure a variable are arbitrary--pounds or drams, angstroms or parsecs--then scaling the variable is an essential mechanism to convert between units. Only when the units have intrinsic meaning (such as counts) would the meaningfulness of scaling be questionable.

Comment: @whuber for any skewed distribution the answer is no. And it has nothing to do with pounds or parsecs, skewed distribution + z-scores = misinterpretation. I had spent quite a lot of time trying to explain why $-2 \sigma != 2\sigma$ for skewed case (and for real data it is somehow more often)

Comment: @whuber you're saying this because you understand what this transformation means. But in real life people think: $z-score(RV) \sim \mathcal N$ and the distribution of $RV$ can be arbitrary. Really, so many things were done wrong because of this (at least from my practice) so I am surprised that you said this. I've seen z-scores of bimodal RVs, skewed RVs, discrete RVs. IDK. You have more experience than I.

Comment: @German The question asks whether an operation "makes sense."  You can't hold me responsible for those who independently do something nonsensical with the results or misinterpret them.  Regardless, I cannot see any justification for your claim that standardizing data from a skewed distribution makes no sense.  Even then it is of great conceptual, practical, and computational value.

Comment: @whuber that's what I meant. People do not apply z-scores for fun, they test for significance. I.e., $3 \sigma = $significance. They overestimate effect from one side and underestimate effect from another. Z-scores are OK for representation, from my point of view, and for nothing else.

Comment: I think I would agree with you, @German, understanding that by "z-score" you mean computing a standardized value *with the intention of referring it to a standard Normal distribution.*  But the current question appears to comprise a large set of more benign applications, ranging from standardizing regression residuals, to understanding correlation in terms of mean products of standardized variables, to stabilizing numerical algorithms, and many more situations where the Normal distribution is neither used nor considered relevant.

Comment: @whuber I agree, but I would try to consider other variance-stabilizing transformations (and then, after such transformation, z-scores are OK). However, I would say that z-scores are OK if the statistician is too lazy to think about the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scaling a variable is a linear transformation and it will not change the distribution of the variable so it does not matter if the variable has a non-normal distribution.

You can confirm this by generating non-normally distributed data in R, such as: `X=rnorm(10000,10,5)^2`. Then, scale the variable "X" `X.z = scale(x)`

Comparing the two histograms: `hist(X)` vs. `hist(X.z)` you'll see the distributions are unchanged.

**EDIT:** As noted in the comments, scaling does influence the interpretation of the parameters when doing many statistical analyses (regression, PCA etc) so the decision to scale should be based on how you want to interpret your parameters.

However, scaling *will not* change the underlying distribution of the variable nor will it influence (positively or negatively) the violations of model assumptions. For example, an assumption of linear regression is *normality of the residuals* scaling a raw variable will not affect this normality.

Comment: Although the *shapes* of distributions are unchanged by scaling, the *distributions* themselves are definitely changed. This might sound like a nit-pick until you contemplate operations like scaling a Poisson distribution: suddenly it's no longer a Poisson distribution at all.

Comment: If isn't a normal distribution, it isn't right to apply a scaling before a Principal Component Analisys process.